# RequestsLibrary - No keyword with name 'POST On Session' found

Tags: robotframework

I'm getting "No keyword with name 'POST On Session' found." but I've already installed requests and requestslibrary. Can you advise?

```
*** Settings ***
Library               Collections
Library               RequestsLibrary

Suite Setup           Create Session    jsonplaceholder    http://128.199.203.18/api/v1

*** Test cases **
Login
    &{data} =    Create Dictionary    email=creditbpo2020@gmail.com    password=analiza123
    ${resp}=  POST On Session  jsonplaceholder     /login    json=${data}  expected_status=any
```

Comment: you either havent installed correctly like, pip is from different python version than the python you are running or you have installed them as separate user and into user specific location and then another user does not have access to it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command to install library

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-requests
```

Then run your test again.

Comment: Run these commands

`pip freeze | grep robotframework` or `pip3 freeze | grep robotframework` and paste the output.